# Trying to Loop via Cursor Through Partition Selection Until Counter Value is Satisfied

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested-loops, database-cursor

I understand that there are other potential options and a cursor may not be the most efficient choice for what I'm trying to accomplish, but be that as it may I'm hoping to gather some guidance on how to structure this query.

My Starting data looks like below which exists within a SELECT statement:

| Date | ID | StartingValue | DailyAdjstVal | UnitAdjustment | EndingValue | SumOfUnitAdjustment (Should Equal DailyAdjstVal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/1/2022 | d | 7 | 6 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| 12/1/2022 | a | 5 | 6 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| 12/1/2022 | c | 4 | 6 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| 12/1/2022 | b | 3 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 12/1/2022 | e | 2 | 6 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 12/2/2022 | b | 8 | 4 | 0 | 8 | 0 |
| 12/2/2022 | c | 4 | 4 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| 12/2/2022 | a | 3 | 4 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 12/2/2022 | d | 2 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 12/2/2022 | e | 2 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 12/3/2022 | d | 6 | 5 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| 12/3/2022 | a | 5 | 5 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| 12/3/2022 | c | 4 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| 12/3/2022 | b | 3 | 5 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 12/3/2022 | e | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

The ending Output I'm trying to produce looks like below, with the last three columns updated by the query:

| Date | ID | StartingValue | DailyAdjstVal | UnitAdjustment | EndingValue | SumOfUnitAdjustment (Should Equal DailyAdjstVal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/1/2022 | d | 7 | 6 | 3 | 4 | 6 |
| 12/1/2022 | a | 5 | 6 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 12/1/2022 | c | 4 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 6 |
| 12/1/2022 | b | 3 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 6 |
| 12/1/2022 | e | 2 | 6 | 0 | 2 | 6 |
| 12/2/2022 | b | 8 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 4 |
| 12/2/2022 | c | 4 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 12/2/2022 | a | 3 | 4 | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| 12/2/2022 | d | 2 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 12/2/2022 | e | 2 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 12/3/2022 | d | 6 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 12/3/2022 | a | 5 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 12/3/2022 | c | 4 | 5 | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 12/3/2022 | b | 3 | 5 | 0 | 3 | 5 |
| 12/3/2022 | e | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

The operation I'm trying to produce is the following steps:

- Cursor should operate within partitions of the data, looking at all values for a date and completing before moving onto the next date within the set until all Date values are completed.
- Sort the set ordering by Date DESC and StartingValue DESC
- Set @Counter = 0
- Beginning with the highest StartingValue for that Date and iterating down, WHILE EndingValue >3, add +1 to UnitAdjustment, -1 to EndingValue, and +1 to @Counter.
- While @Counter < DailyAdjstVal, load the next row and perform the same as above.
- If Cursor reaches the end of the partition set, it should start again with the first row in the series and continue until @Counter = DailyAdjstVal. After which time it should load the next date and begin the process again with the same logic.
- Once it completes the process, it should update SumOfUnitAdjustment to total all EndingValue based on Date Partition which should, then, equal to DailyAdjstVal.

I believe for this process I'll need two cursors with the first to iterate through Days within the table set and an Inner cursor to perform the cell and @Counter updates. Apologies if there's any confusion in my steps, I appreicate any assistance!

Comment: You should be able to solve that with window functions...

Comment: @DaleK I've tried a few attempts at that, but my problem has been using a window function to deduct in sequence up to the given Adjustment amount.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75808099/edit) your question to include the code you've tried to use and explain why you think it isn't meeting your requirements. You're asking for assistance, not to make use of a free contract coding service.

Comment: Without having fully understood what you are trying to do, it's potentially a gaps -and-islands problem. Even if it's not, looking into them should give you some insight. But as already mentioned, show us your window function attempt and soneone will most likely help you complete it

Comment: So as I reimagine the problem, for each date we have N rows having a defined order each with a potential adjustment = `StartingValue - 3` (not less than zero) and an available adjustment `DailyAdjstVal` for that date that we would like to distribute across those rows. There are straight-forward ways to distribute integral amounts evenly across rows, but having a per-row limit complicates things. This might require some kind of recursive CTE to iterate down the counts for each date to find the solution for that date. (Let me work in that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I re-imagine the problem, for each date, we have N rows having a defined order, each with a potential adjustment = StartingValue - 3 (not less than zero), and an available adjustment DailyAdjstVal for that date that we would like to distribute across those rows.

Although there are relatively simple ways to distribute integral amounts evenly across rows, having a per-row limit complicates things and requires a more involved approach.

Below is SQL that gathers some initial information for each date, uses a recursive CTE to step through increasing levels of adjustments until the adjustment budget is exhausted, selects the maximum viable adjustment for each date (with residuals), and then applies those adjustments to the starting data.

```
;WITH OrderedData AS (
    -- Assign a sequence number for rows having dame date.
    -- Calculate potential adjustment per row.
    SELECT
        Date, ID, StartingValue, DailyAdjstVal,
        GREATEST(0, StartingValue - @ThresholdValue) AS PotentialAdjust,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY StartingValue DESC, ID) AS Seq
    FROM StartingData
),
DailyAdjust AS (
    -- Get potential adjustment stats per date
    SELECT OD.Date,
        MAX(OD.DailyAdjstVal) AS DailyAdjstVal,
        SUM(OD.PotentialAdjust) AS SumPotentialAdjust,
        MAX(OD.PotentialAdjust) AS MaxPotentialAdjust
    FROM OrderedData OD
    GROUP BY OD.Date
),
RowsPerAdjustment AS (
    -- For each date and adjustmenr value combination, calculate the
    -- number of rows that could be adjusted to that level.
    -- Skip if DailyAdjstVal will cover all potential adjustments.
    SELECT DA.Date, S.Adjust, C.AdjustCount
    FROM DailyAdjust DA
    CROSS APPLY (Select value FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, LEAST(DA.DailyAdjstVal, DA.MaxPotentialAdjust))) S(Adjust)
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS AdjustCount
        FROM OrderedData OD
        WHERE OD.Date = DA.Date
        AND OD.PotentialAdjust >= S.Adjust
    ) C
    WHERE DA.DailyAdjstVal < DA.SumPotentialAdjust
    AND C.AdjustCount > 0
),
Adjustments AS (
    -- Use a recursive CTE to effectively loop through the adjustment levels
    -- for each date until we have exhausted our available adjustment.
    -- Skip if DailyAdjstVal will cover all potential adjustments.
    -- (There might also be a way to do this using window functions at this point)
    SELECT
        DA.Date,
        0 AS Adjust,
        DA.DailyAdjstVal AS ResidualAdjust,
        DA.MaxPotentialAdjust
    FROM DailyAdjust DA
    WHERE DA.DailyAdjstVal < DA.SumPotentialAdjust

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        A.Date,
        A.Adjust + 1 AS Adjust,
        A.ResidualAdjust - RPA.AdjustCount AS ResidualAdjust,
        A.MaxPotentialAdjust
    FROM Adjustments A
    JOIN RowsPerAdjustment RPA
        ON RPA.Date = A.Date
        AND RPA.Adjust = A.Adjust + 1
    WHERE 1=1
    AND A.ResidualAdjust > 0
    AND A.Adjust < A.MaxPotentialAdjust
    AND A.ResidualAdjust >= RPA.AdjustCount
),
SelectedAdjustment AS (
    -- Now select the greatest level of adjustment.
    -- ResidualAdjust reflects the remaining adjustments allocated to less
    -- than all eligible rows
    SELECT A.date, MAX(A.Adjust) AS Adjust, MIN(A.ResidualAdjust) AS ResidualAdjust
    FROM Adjustments A
    GROUP BY A.Date
)
--SELECT * FROM OrderedData ORDER BY Date, Seq
--SELECT * FROM DailyAdjust ORDER BY Date
--SELECT * FROM RowsPerAdjustment ORDER BY Date, Adjust
--SELECT * FROM Adjustments ORDER BY Date, Adjust
--SELECT * FROM SelectedAdjustment ORDER BY Date
SELECT
    -- Loose the hounds
    OD.Date, OD.ID, OD.StartingValue AS StartVal, OD.DailyAdjstVal AS DailyAdj,
    --OD.PotentialAdjust AS PA,
    --DA.SUMPotentialAdjust AS SumPA,
    --DA.MaxPotentialAdjust AS MaxPA,
    --SA.Adjust, SA.ResidualAdjust AS ResAdj,
    A.UnitAdjustment AS UnitAdj,
    OD.StartingValue - A.UnitAdjustment AS EndVal,
    SUM(A.UnitAdjustment) OVER(PARTITION BY OD.Date) AS SumAdj
FROM OrderedData OD
JOIN DailyAdjust DA ON DA.Date = OD.Date
LEFT JOIN SelectedAdjustment SA ON SA.Date = OD.Date
CROSS APPLY (
    -- Calculate full or partial adjustment
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN DA.SumPotentialAdjust <= DA.DailyAdjstVal 
        THEN OD.PotentialAdjust 
        ELSE LEAST(SA.Adjust, OD.PotentialAdjust)
             + CASE WHEN OD.Seq < SA.ResidualAdjust THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        END AS UnitAdjustment
) A
ORDER BY OD.date, OD.Seq
```

I believe the Adjustments, RowsPerAdjustment, and SelectedAdjustment steps can be combined into a nested query with some window functions that don't require a recursive CTE, but I am out of time at the moment. I may update this answer in a day or two.

The above is for SQL Server 2022. If you are using an earlier version, you will need to replace references to GREATEST() and LEAST() functions with equivalent CASE statements and replace the GENERATE_SERIES() with an alternative number generator.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/d69O1W1f) for a working example (with an extra case where the DailyAdjstVal exceeds eligible adjustments).

Sample results.

| Date | ID | StartVal | DailyAdj | UnitAdj | EndVal | SumAdj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01 | d | 7 | 6 | 3 | 4 | 6 |
| 2022-12-01 | a | 5 | 6 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 2022-12-01 | c | 4 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 6 |
| 2022-12-01 | b | 3 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 6 |
| 2022-12-01 | e | 2 | 6 | 0 | 2 | 6 |
| 2022-12-02 | b | 8 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 4 |
| 2022-12-02 | c | 4 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 2022-12-02 | a | 3 | 4 | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| 2022-12-02 | d | 2 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 2022-12-02 | e | 2 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 2022-12-03 | d | 6 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 2022-12-03 | a | 5 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 2022-12-03 | c | 4 | 5 | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 2022-12-03 | b | 3 | 5 | 0 | 3 | 5 |
| 2022-12-03 | e | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| 2022-12-04 | z | 6 | 9 | 3 | 3 | 6 |
| 2022-12-04 | y | 5 | 9 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 2022-12-04 | x | 4 | 9 | 1 | 3 | 6 |
| 2022-12-04 | w | 3 | 9 | 0 | 3 | 6 |
| 2022-12-04 | v | 2 | 9 | 0 | 2 | 6 |

**Addendum**: For SQL Server 2019, the following changes may be made to eliminate references to `LEAST()`, `GREATEST()`, and `GENERATE_SERIES()`.

1. the `PotentialAdjust` calculation can be replaced with:

```
        CASE WHEN StartingValue > @ThresholdValue
            THEN StartingValue - @ThresholdValue
            ELSE 0
            END AS PotentialAdjust,
```

2. The following new CTE can be inserted immediately before the `RowsPerAdjustment` CTE:

```
Series AS (
    -- Series of numbers from 1 to Max PotentialAdjust across all dates
    -- (Order doesn't matter 1..N is the same as N..1)
    SELECT Max(MaxPotentialAdjust) AS Adjust
    FROM DailyAdjust DA

    UNION ALL

    SELECT S.Adjust - 1 AS Adjust
    FROM Series S
    WHERE S.Adjust > 1
),
```

3. The `CROSS APPLY ... GENERATE_SERIES ...` can now be replaced with:

```
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT S.Adjust
        FROM Series S
        WHERE S.Adjust <= DA.DailyAdjstVal    -- whichever is lower
        AND S.Adjust <= DA.MaxPotentialAdjust -- whichever is lower
    ) S
```

4. At the end or the query, the `UnitAdjustment` calculation can be replaced with:

```
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN DA.SumPotentialAdjust <= DA.DailyAdjstVal 
        THEN OD.PotentialAdjust -- All rows (for this date) are fully adjusted
        WHEN OD.PotentialAdjust <= SA.Adjust
        THEN OD.PotentialAdjust -- This row is fully adjusted
        ELSE SA.Adjust + CASE WHEN OD.Seq < SA.ResidualAdjust THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        END AS UnitAdjustment
```

See [this updated db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LwQUmemJ) targetting SQL Server 2019.

I may still look at combining the RowsPerAdjustment, Adjustments, and SelectedAdjustment CTEs, but this may take another day or two.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your effort and assistance to this problem! I very much appreciate it all! 

I've been working on trying to adapt your code and I've gotten stuck at the Generate_Series part, I'm operating on SQL Server 19 unfortunately and don't have access to that bit....Producing a series in line with your code has been a separate challenge I've been working through unfortunately..

Comment: You are welcome. It was an interesting problem.  Generalized as an algorithm for evenly distributing an amount among unequal containers of limited, possibly unequal capacities. My current solution is more complicated than I had hoped, but there is still room for improvement.

Comment: Amazing! You've taught me that I really should be using CTEs more often....